# Streams and abstraction

Tags: c, stream

I'm studying about C (ANSI) I/O and C (Unix) I/O and I have the following question:

If everything on a computer without abstraction is a stream of data(or dataflow, call it what you want), regardless of whether it came from a file or a socket, why do I need an abstraction layer called stream to handle this?

Comment: You do not _need_ the abstraction layer.  It was simpier than other choices.  What do you otherwise suggest?

Comment: but...you need it just _because_ several things have this in common. Cf. "Play" button for music and video - that was a common interface before computers. (But you cannot "play" an image). You can look at the film roll directly, and get the idea, but then you'll want that "Play" button. Others say: if I keep blinking while I gently pull that strip...

Answer (score 2):

There are no abstractions inside a machine. The abstractions are all inside your head. "Dataflow" is an abstraction you use to think about very distinct mechanisms; if you view a computer "without abstractions", you won't see any "streams of data".

The "abstraction layer" is a concrete interface designed to make a bunch of complicated and idiosyncratic mechanisms controllable in a way which corresponds to the abstraction you use to design programs.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I understood what you said, I started from a wrong premise: that somehow this dataflow existed.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm studying about C ansi I/O and C unix I/O and i had the following
> question:
>
> if everything on a computer without abstraction is a stream of data(or
> dataflow, call it what you want), regardless of whether it came from a
> file or a socket, why do I need an abstraction layer called stream to
> handle this?

I think you are confused about where the key abstraction lies: it is exactly the embodiment of the UNIX design philosophy that "everything is a file", realized in part by the fact that one set of low-level POSIX I/O functions handles all devices.  Using those I/O functions is *not* accessing the computer without (device) abstraction.

On a POSIX system, you do not *need* streams, but it is often convenient to use them, at least because

1. they provide a richer, higher-level abstraction than raw I/O does, and
2. they are more portable to non-POSIX systems.

On a non-POSIX system you possibly do need streams, because the low-level POSIX I/O functions may not exist.  The latter are not specified by the C language standard, but rather by POSIX.

Comment: yes i understood now, the ideia that "everything is a file" is alredy a abstraction due to the posix pattern. thanks for the answer. my question now is "how the idea that everything was a file" was made? with the idea of inode + fs-unix ? thanks.

Comment: That would be a separate question, @joaovictorRosmaninho, and probably off-topic for SO.  It might be more appropriate for [Retrocomputing SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/), but you should probably think a bit about what you really want to know.  After all, the answer to how the idea was made ultimately comes down simply to somebody just coming up with it.  Note also that it has nothing in particular to do with i-nodes, though it is related to UNIX's single-rooted hierarchical filesystem.